# How can I do something only after the DOM has loaded after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="mydiv">
    ...
    <a id="my-ajax-link"> ... </a>

    ...
    ...

    <select id="my-selectmenu"> 
        ... 
    </select>
    ...
</div>
```

I have a link 'my-ajax-link' clicking upon which an AJAX call is fired, which updates the content of div 'mydiv'.

I want to do something with the select menu through jQuery only after the DOM in the div 'mydiv' has loaded completely after the AJAX call.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where's the AJAX call?  What loading message?  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: `I want to do something with the select menu through jQuery only after the div is loaded completely after the AJAX call,` ? which div you are talking about here?

Comment: Strongly suggest you read [ask] ... and ...  create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just use ajax calback:

```
$.ajax({
...
}).always(function(response_data) {
  alert('ajax finished');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it sounds like you want to change something in the DOM after the Ajax request is completed, and not while it is being processed. You should look into the [done() function](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://test.com/url/to/call',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    }
}).done(function(result) {
    //
    // Code you want executed AFTER ajax call completes
    // Where result is the response from the server after ajax finishes the call
    //
});
```